# How to add options to drop down menu in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to add options to a drop down menu based on the data in a separate list.

```
class taskList(discord.ui.View):
        jobs = 0
        global data
        optionList = []
        
        for job in data["Server"]["Tasking"]:
            if len(job) > 0:
                jobs += 1
                optionList[discord.SelectOption(label=job,value=jobs,description="")]
                
        @discord.ui.select(
            placeholder="Choose Role",
            min_values=1,
            max_values=1,
            options=optionList
        )
        async def select_callback(self,select,interaction):
            ""
```

Is this even possible and if it's, how do I go about doing this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: use `optionList.append` your code is currently trying to get the index with the created SelectOption instance which is not possible